# Configuring UTL_MAIL Package Prerequisites

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I was trying to configure my system to send mail using UTL_MAIL package but no luck .. I read that I need to configure ACL first.  hence I did. But even doing so it's not working still.

```
SELECT * FROM dba_network_acls;

begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
    acl         => 'utl_http.xml',
    description => 'HTTP Access',
    principal   => 'HR',
    is_grant    => TRUE,
    privilege   => 'connect',
    start_date  => null,
    end_date    => null
  );
  dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege (
    acl        => 'utl_http.xml',
    principal  => 'HR',
    is_grant   => TRUE,
    privilege  => 'resolve',
    start_date => null,
    end_date   => null
  );
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
    acl        => 'utl_http.xml',
    host       => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    lower_port => 25,  --- Gmail SMTP server.
    upper_port => 25
  );
  commit;
end;
/
```

I am getting error

**ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ei4sm3659171pbb.42 - gsmtp
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 654
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 671
ORA-06512: at line 2
29279. 00000 -  "SMTP permanent error: %s"
*Cause:    A SMTP permanent error occurred.
*Action:   Correct the error and retry the SMTP operation.**

I have already executed the following commands

CONN sys/password AS SYSDBA

@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlmail.sql

@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/prvtmail.plb

Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SMTP server appears to require an encrypted connection.  `UTL_MAIL` is designed to simplify the API for sending mail for basic SMTP servers.  It doesn't support the full set of options defined by the SMTP protocol.  I don't believe it supports TLS.

Assuming that you're using 11.2, you'll need to use the UTL_SMTP package and you'll need to call the [STARTTLS function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS73117) while you're setting up the connection.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. I am using 11.2G .

Comment: BTW: for many practical reasons the only SMTP server you should use from Oracle has to be 127.0.0.1 (localhost). So Oracle will handover the mail to a local SMTP server, which is very fast, always succeeds and is logged in /var/log/maillog. Then it is responsibility of the local SMTP to deliver that email.

Comment: @Ivan - That's certainly a reasonable option.  But it's not the only reasonable option.  Someone has to monitor the local SMTP server, for example, while the corporate email server is probably already being monitored.  Going directly to the corporate server also allows the application to receive an error if email is down which may be useful for users-- for example, it may be useful to let the user know that email will be delayed or to log that the SMTP server was down if a lack of email might create support requests.