# How to send email using PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, email, stored-procedures, plsql

Hi friends I have an assignment in which my task is to write a pl/sql procedure used to send email which uses gmail as mail server.

I write this procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_domain IN varchar2, 
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 465) AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.ehlo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_domain);  
  UTL_SMTP.command(l_mail_conn,'AUTH LOGIN');  
  UTL_SMTP.command(l_mail_conn,utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('mygmail@gmail.com')));
  UTL_SMTP.command(l_mail_conn,utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('mypassword')));
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);
  UTL_SMTP.data(l_mail_conn, p_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```

Procedure created successfully

TO execute this procedure I used following code

```
BEGIN
  send_mail(p_to        => 'someone@gmail.com',
            p_from      => 'mygmail@gmail.com',
            p_message   => 'This is a test message.',
            p_smtp_host => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        p_smtp_domain => 'gmail.com'
);
END;
/
```

After executing I got following error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 17
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 96
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 138
ORA-06512: at "ZAHID.SEND_MAIL", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

If I changed the port number 25 then I got this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t9sm10042472wjf.41
- gsmtp
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 17
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 98
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 158
ORA-06512: at "ZAHID.SEND_MAIL", line 13
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

My oracle version is Oracle9i, I searched a lot of for solution of above errors but not successful, please review my code and helped me to solve it, I shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring UTL\_MAIL Package Prerequisites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763930/configuring-utl-mail-package-prerequisites)

Comment: not understand sathya, it's not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think `421 Service not available error` is? You need to provide the smtp credentials.

Oracle is just the victim, culprit is the mail server configuration. Do :

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET smtp_out_server = 'your_config' scope=spfile;
```

And then give the proper credentials. Try with a test email. Have a look at http://www.orafaq.com/forum/m/588498/?srch=421+Service+not+available#msg_588498

To conclude, **Your SMTP server is not started.** Perhaps, I was not clear above,

`ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available` means that the credentials are not correct.

`ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t9sm10042472wjf.41 - gsmtp` means that SMTP server is not started. For which STARTTLS command is required.

---

### Update : Folks, my sincere apologies that I completely missed that OP already mentioned he is on 9i.

Comment: he has given credentials (line# 3 of send_mail). utl_mail doesn't support TLS, as mentioned by Justin the linked question and gmail requires TLS to start authentication

Comment: I know, and that's why I mentioned the link which has the suggestion "Your SMTP server is not started." Perhaps, I should add this in my answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? This is not quite clear to me: does the OP error implies the server requires TSL ? Changing the configuration will fix that ?

Comment: ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available means that the credentials are not correct.

ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t9sm10042472wjf.41
- gsmtp means that SMTP server is not started. For which STARTTLS command is required.

Comment: SMTP server isn't something the OP starts, SMTP server he's connecting to is Gmail's. if gmail's smtp server "isn't started", pretty sure everyone would notice. This answer is completely wrong now.

Comment: when did I say that SMTP is started by OP? When he used UTL_SMTP.open_connection it opens a connection to the SMTP server. OP firstly did not provide the correct credentials, then when he modified the port number, he got the error SMTP server is not started. Because, it needs to be explicitly done.

Comment: You've bolded in the answer - "To conclude, Your SMTP server is not started. "

Comment: Yes, so? OP has not explicitly used STARTTLS command for the connection request using UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION

Comment: There is a *world* of difference between "STARTTLS command" is not issued and "SMTP server is not started". You're implying the latter, while ignoring the fact that STARTLS support isn't there in UTL_SMTP.

Comment: Ah, user is not on 11gR2, i just realized he mentioned he is on 9i :-(

Comment: Guys I am not understand what's you want to say but I request you please answer this question in just 3 steps from start to end. Thanks

Comment: @MTO_UPAP step 1. Upgrade to Oracle 11g r2+ step 2: ... step 3: profit!

Comment: And I sincerely apologize as I didn't see that OP mentioned he is on 9i. I just kept discussing as I assumed back of my mind that OP is on 11gR2 in his production system.

Comment: +1 @sathya for the comment to intimate OP to upgrade to 11gR2